# Update/Insert queries with Data Direct DB2 JDBC driver for tables which are not journalled

Tags: java, node.js, database, db2, apigee

I have used IBM DB2 iSeries database in my application. I have connected my application to database via DataDirect approach by db2.jar (DataDirect given by Progress) in node.js. With this approach I can fetch data by select query but I am not able to update/insert data in non-journalled tables. But same update/insert works well if I use jt400.jar of JTOpen.

But in our node.js application is connected via db2.jar not with jt400.jar. I face same problem if I use java code instead of node.  I have used below update query in Squirrel Client connected with db2.jar -

```
UPDATE MSSTQACEYK.MXAPGI001 SET PRCSD = 'Y' WHERE ORDNO = 'P544901'
```

It throws below error in both case either I use node.js or Java -

```
Error: [DataDirect][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]Error occured with SQLCode -7008 with the following parameters: MXAPGI001 , MSSTQACEYK, 3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
SQLState:  55019
ErrorCode: -7008
```

Below is sample java code I used to check this operation -

```
{
   String sql = "INSERT INTO MSSTQACEYK.MXAPGI001 (ORDNO) VALUES ('P544901') ";
   Class.forName("com.ddtek.jdbc.db2.DB2Driver");
   String url = "jdbc:datadirect:db2://hostname:port;DatabaseName=APG;";
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "UName","Pass");
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
   System.out.println("Record Inserted");
}
```

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 0):

The IBM JDBC driver includes a property, "transaction isolation", which when set to "none" allows you to update/insert into a non-journaled table.

See if your DataDirect driver supports that property.

[IBM i JDBC docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm)

Comment: This we can do in java by setIsolationLevel() but I am having node.js as data layer and here I am not having any option like this. Is there any other way to do this???